# Spyder installation without Anaconda using pip

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, pip, anaconda, spyder

In order to install `Spyder` without `Anaconda` installation in `Windows 10 (64 bit)`, I execute stages as follow:

```
 1. python -m pip install pyqt5
 2. python -m pip install spyder
 3. python -m pip install PyQtWebEngine
 4. spyder3 (to launch spyder)
```

I utilize `Python 3.6.8`.
After installation is completed, I type `spyder3` in `CMD` and press `enter`. But, just `Spyder` icon is appeared and `Spyder` cannot be launched. Also, when I go to script folder of Python and run `Spyder.exe`, such problem occurs, too. Why it happens and what I do?
Briefly, just this image is shown:
[image: Spyder Initialization]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installation, I run this code in CMD:

```
pip install spyder-kernels==1.*
```

Finally, it worked for me.